# Setting Locale Programmatically not working?

Tags: android, locale

I have an activity where I programmatically set the locale to "de" and it doesn't work as expected and displays the default language (English text) that is manually set. Please help

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
        //Programmatically sets the locale and language  
        Locale locale = new Locale("de");  
        Locale.setDefault(locale);  
        Configuration config = new Configuration();  
        config.locale = locale;   
        getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());   

       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  

        setContentView(R.layout.main);  
Intent intent=new Intent(LatestLocalizationActivity.this,AnotherActivity.class);  
       startActivity(intent);  
}
```

Comment: instead of using the getBaseContext(), try using the getApplicationContext()

Answer (score 6):

had you add the Strings.xml file in res->value-de folder?

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
        //Programmatically sets the locale and language
                    setContentView(R.layout.main); 
                    config = getBaseContext().getResources().getConfiguration(); 
                    locale = new Locale("de");
                    Locale.setDefault(locale);
                    config.locale = locale;
                    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
                    refresh();



       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  


}



@Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        Configuration config = getBaseContext().getResources().getConfiguration();
      // refresh your views here
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        config.locale = locale;
      super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }



private void refresh() {
        finish();
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(yourActivity.this, yourActivity.class);
        startActivity(myIntent);
    }
```

Comment: yeah I have added it and also i have added android:configChanges="locale" in manifest.

Comment: I have tried even the above thing. But it works only if I have a single activity. From "LatestLocalizationActivity" I am passing intent and startin "anotherActivity" but it displays second activity's view.

Comment: okay, then i have to google for that will get back to you if any update

Comment: thank you..pls do it. I am trying from my side too for the solution

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me:

```
public static void changeLocale(Context context, Locale locale) {
    Configuration conf = context.getResources().getConfiguration();
    conf.locale = locale;
    Locale.setDefault(locale);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        conf.setLayoutDirection(conf.locale);
    }

    context.getResources().updateConfiguration(conf, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
}
```

please use your ACTIVITY CONTEXT and not your application context.

Answer (score 3):

Note that while you may be able to hack on things to kind-of get something like this to work, Android does not currently support doing this in a robust way.  In particular, the framework works the current configuration in the resources, and will update it when it thinks appropriate.  You will be fighting with this, and it is unlikely you are going to be able to have no situations where the configuration reverts back to the system locale.